# Can I detect if key is being held down when window gains focus?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, onfocus

I am tracking keyDown and keyUp to show whether or not the shift key is being pressed in JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",doKeyDown,false);
window.addEventListener("keyup",doKeyUp,false);
var shiftKeyDown = false;

function doKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.keyCode==16) { shiftKeyDown = true; }
}

function doKeyUp(e) {
    if (e.keyCode==16) { shiftKeyDown = false; }
}
```

However, the user might hold the shift key down while giving focus to another window, so my window never hears the `keyup` event. Am I right in thinking that there is no way to detect the state of the shift key when the window gains focus again, so I can correctly update `shiftKeyDown`?

Comment: I think you could rely on `event.shiftKey` property which is supported in both mouse and keyboard events. Unfortunately, I don't know if that's the case about focus events, especially on window

Comment: @eithed I wondered the same thing, but it is unfortunately not supported in focus events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `window.onBlur` eventlistener and set `shiftKeyDown` to false, when the windows loses focus.

```
window.addEventListener("blur",onBlur,false);
function onBlur(e){ 
    shiftKeyDown = false 
}
```

Comment: This isn't technically a perfect solution but I'm accepting the answer because it's an excellent workaround that will much more closely match user expectation. Thank you!